# .NET 4.0 application crashing due to exception code 0xc0000005

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know there are so many questions regarding exception code `0xc0000005` but I don't find any of them same as I am facing. Application is getting crashed as soon as I execute it, Detailed event log is as follows:

```
Faulting application name: TestApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x588783fe
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00cba8ed
Faulting process id: 0x960
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2881a98879a57
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\TestApp.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: d8f71de8-f40d-11e6-83a2-4437e63fc852
```

I have used log4j to log all the errors but no errors are logged and I am not getting why `Faulting module name` is unknown in event log?

In this test application I have only added code to show message box on form_load event. I have tried after re-installing .NET framework 4.0 still the same issue is coming.

**Update**
This is not the scenario to all the clients some of our client(s) are facing this issue.

Comment: In event log check log below this. Usually there is error message with stack trace.

Comment: Also, if you can't see the stack trace from event log or you can't run a debugger. You may want to use [procdump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) with your app. `procdump -ma -e your.exe`. This will create a dump file if an unhandled exception is encountered. Then just load the dump file and see the stack trace.

Comment: Log more than just errors - log "everything", i.e. function entered/exited, thus you'll see better where it crashes.

Comment: @IlianPinzon I have taken the dump (dmp file) generated by procdump and opened in Visual studio 2010 but I didn't find any stack trace. I have uploaded the dump information [here](http://txt.do/d1zqu) which is copied from VS2010.